# mySQL Error near AS

Tags: mysql, sql

Can anyone help with this? I've just switched web servers and I'm testing everything is working but I'm seeing this error. Any ideas whats wrong with the query? It seemed to be valid on my last host

```
Critical Error
        A database error has occoured.
        Error Returned mySQL query error: SELECT f.* AS fixtures,
                    team1.teamName AS HomeTeam,
                    team1.tid AS HomeTeamID,
                    team2.teamName AS AwayTeam,
                    team2.tid AS AwayTeamID,
       GROUP_CONCAT(n.extra separator ',') AS scorers,
       GROUP_CONCAT(n.homeEvent separator ',') AS homeEvent,
       GROUP_CONCAT(n.eventType separator ',') AS eventType
    FROM fixtures f
    LEFT JOIN notifications n ON n.fixtureID = f.fid
    LEFT JOIN teams team1 ON team1.tid = f.HomeTeam
    LEFT JOIN teams team2 ON team2.tid = f.AwayTeam
    WHERE f.kickoff > 1403823600 AND f.lid=1
    GROUP BY f.fid
    ORDER BY n.time ASC, f.kickoff ASC
```

mySQL error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'AS fixtures,
>                           team1.teamName AS HomeTeam,
>                           team1.tid AS HomeTeamID,
>                       ' at line 1

Comment: `f.* AS fixtures` all column values in a single column ??? what ????

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't cast a wildcard like that.. Casting is only for single fields

```
SELECT f.* AS fixtures
```

Try something like

```
SELECT f.fixtures AS fixtures, f.field AS field
```

etc

Comment: turns out what I meant was just `SELECT f.*` Don't know what I was smoking when I wrote that or why it didnt throw an error before. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what kind of sql engine did you run on your previous webserver, but this is actually not allowed:

```
SELECT f.* AS fixtures
```

You need to specify a column, you can't use the wildcard for casting.

Comment: I'm beginning to question a lot about my old host.